# How can I change my cURL call to recognise more than 1 parameter?

Tags: rest, curl, oauth, call

I want to make the following curl call to get an access token:

```
curl -k -XPOST --user "{user}" {url}/access_token -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code={code}&redirect_uri={uri}'
```

However, I get the following error statement:

```
'code' is not recognized as ane internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
'redirect_uri' is not recognized as ane internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

When I check the trace, I see that the body only contains this: `'grant_type=authorization_code`

What can I do to make sure all the parameters get passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
curl -X "POST" "{url}/access_token" \
 --user "{user}" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
 --data-urlencode "code={code}" \
 --data-urlencode "redirect_uri={uri}" \
 --data-urlencode "grant_type=authorization_code"
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the &-character is interpreted as "execute as background job". Try escaping each &-character with a backslash - like \&

Alternatively you could write your content into a file and reference this file via the parameter -d @file
The @-character is important for curl to know that file is a file name.